# Is there any way to get POST data from check.php to both index.php & thanks.php?

Tags: php, post

My goal is to make my form display error messages just below of each input text form on my index.php when there's blank as the picture showed below. I don't want to use any frameworks like Laravel or Cakephp, but just use POST method.
[image: Ideal completion image]

At the moment, I get no message but redirected to index.php when there's blank.

Here is my input.php code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Practice1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="check.php" method="post">
    <h1>Input form</h1>
    <div class="content">
    Last Name&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="last-name" value=""class="">
    <?php if(isset($errors['lastName'])) : ?>
        <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars("") ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
    Name&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="first-name" value="">
    <?php if (isset($errors['firstName'])): ?>
    <p><?php echo $errors['firstName'] ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my check.php code

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "POST"){
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
}
$firstName = $_POST['first-name'];
$lastName = $_POST['last-name'];

if ($lastName == "" || $firstName == ""){
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
}

$errors = ['lastName' => '※required', 'firstName' => '※required'];

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>confirm</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="thanks.php index.php" method="post">
    <h1>confirm</h1>
    <div class="content">
    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($lastName) ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($firstName) ?></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: you are issuing a header redirect and exiting, so the following line which sets errors is never called... Don't try to remove the exit line, it will do the same thing, as the header location is "processed" immediately by the browser upon reception.

Comment: you have to encode the errors structure properly to be passed as a GET parameter to the redirect script (if this is what you want to do), with url_encode for example

Comment: You could also look into submitting the form using Ajax. Then you don't need to reload the page or add stuff to the URL to be able to show the error messages

Comment: I have already tried to encode the errors structure above the redirect structure, but the result's been still the same..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I prefer not to use other languages rather than PHP and HTML.